# How to highlight some dates on calendar in android

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

I'm doing calendar application in android.My code from : http://code.google.com/query/#q=android%20calendar
here i can pick up date from calendar.But i need to mark some date on it.for ex.when i gave any date.,it should be highlighted on my calendar.How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you call

```
setDate()
```

method, this will do the job for you.

Comment: There s no method like setDate() ive called on that example.Where to call?i didnt do this calendar application before.can u guide me?

Comment: Can you give me the link to your code, the one you gived is only a google search..

Comment: Please take a look @ this link http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/downloads/detail?name=Calendar.v0.5.0.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: I suggest you to use the Android calendar view with the android calendar class and then you will have the access to the setDate() method. Or make you calendar class enxtend the android calendar if possible.

Comment: Milos, can you give an example of `se the Android calendar view with the android calendar class and then you will have the access to the setDate() method`